# R: Replace rare values by "others"

Tags: r, indexing

I have the following problem: I have a data frame *df* with many variables. One variable is *df$size* (non-numeric). Now I want to replace all sizes with less than 20 observations by the term "other".

```
sort(table(df$size))
```

This gives me an overview of the values I want to replace. But how do I replace them in my df?

```
df$size[sort(table(df$size))<20]="other"
```

That does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a sample data for the above commands, so that people can help you more easily. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = size) %>%
   mutate(size = replace(size, n() < 20, "other")) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with something along this

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(size = as.character(sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tabs <- sort(table(df$size))
tab <- tabs[tabs < 20]

df$size[which(df$size %in% names(tab))] <- "other"
```

Answer (score 0):

a `library(data.table)` answer:

```
setDT(df)
cnts <- df[,.N, size]
df <- df[cnts, nomatch= 0L, on= 'size'][, size := ifelse(N < 20, 'other', size)]
```

the class type `table` is a bit more difficult to work with in conjunction with data frames. Here we use `cnts` to keep everything within a single object class.